Intel Error while launching Gazebo on Ubuntu 20.04
Hello everyone,
While launching Gazebo on Ubuntu 20.04, I am getting an Intel error message and after sometime it automatically gets killed and I am unable to get lidar data from the Gazebo simulation because of this issue.
Please help me to solve this problem
~gazebo
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: 
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available


Please edit your question to provide a minimum example of how to reproduce your problem. This looks more like a warning, and if there's not an immediate crash after its likely something else causing the problems. Details of what you're environment is and what exactly you're running are critical to help you.

Found the Solution for the above problem
Please type the below commands in the terminal the issue will be solved( Updating Mesa driver)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


Reference document: https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/
